# safecracker file field_type download

Tags: safecracker, ee2-upgrades, safecracker-file

It seems is no longer available for download?
Since I have EE 2.7 installed I'm limited to using the FILE fieldtype, which doesn't seem to work when I try to upload a file logged in as a member of the "Guest" Membergroup. Anybody with similar experience?

Answer (score 2):

Safecracker (and Safecracker File fieldtype) is deprecated for EE 2.7+. Read about it here: http://ellislab.com/blog/entry/expressionengine-2.7.0-released

You have to use the native File fieldtype (instead of Safecracker File fieldtype) with the new native Channel Form module.

Then, you need to make sure your Guest member group has permission to post/edit in the channel you are trying to upload files to. Members > Member Groups > Edit Group (select your group) > Channel Assignment

Comment: You'll also need to make sure the upload directory has permissions for the guest group as well.